# Add Ivy managed dependencies to Android build path

Tags: android, dependencies, ivy, ivyde

Using Eclipse and Ivy, I'm successfully able to download and manage dependencies. These dependencies are added to Eclipse's build path using [IvyDE's container](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/create.html).

However, Android does not find the dependencies. As a workaround, I have to add each Ivy-managed dependency to the build path manually.

Is there a cleaner approach? Can IvyDE be configured with Android in mind?

Comment: We took the decision to use Ivy because it appeared simpler (we only needed dependency management) and is designed to integrate with `ant`. Beginning to think Maven might have been the better option...

Comment: Ivy's a fine tool and a superior dependency manager when compared to Maven (IMHO). However... Maven has a larger install base and better IDE integration. Unless you've got an ANT legacy to defend (unlikely considering Android is so new) I'd recommend learning a new build technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of [ADT](https://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) (r16 at the time of writing) has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an Android developer, so don't have a specific solution.

I could suggest that you investigate ivy's [artifactreport](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactreport.html) task. It generates an XML file, which perhaps you could use to automatically generate the build path.